# Group chronologically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to get the top result from each status from a table grouped by customer id and status, ordered by time.

The data given:

```
CustNo Date       Status
 1      2016-03-24 C
 1      2016-02-08 C
 1      2016-01-17 A
 1      2015-12-04 C
 2      2016-04-28 B
 2      2016-03-25 C
 2      2016-02-13 C
 2      2016-01-04 C
 3      2016-02-02 A
 3      2016-01-09 A
 3      2015-12-12 A
 3      2015-11-30 A
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
CustNo Date       Status
1      2016-03-24 C
1      2016-01-17 A
1      2015-12-04 C
2      2016-04-28 B
2      2016-03-25 C
3      2016-02-02 A
```

As you can see I want the top date for each status change (if any) within each customer. I solved it for customer 2 and 3 where there is no change of status or the status never changes back, but as for customer 1 the status has changed from C to A and back to C and this is the tricky part (for me at least). I always seem to get the C status grouped all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
With CTE as 
{
    select CustNo,
            DATE,
            Status,
            ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by CustNo order by date) as ord
    from tab
)

SELECT  CustNo,
        DATE,
        Status
FROM CTE
EXCEPT
SELECT  C1.CustNo,
        C1.DATE,
        C1.Status
FROM CTE C1
    INNER JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.CustNo = C2.CustNo 
                        AND C1.Status = C2.Status
                        AND C1.ord + 1 = C2.ord
```

Comment: What if there will be `C C C A C`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed function `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate groups:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY Date) -
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo, Status ORDER BY Date) AS grp
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT CustNo, Status, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM cte
GROUP BY CustNo, Status, grp
ORDER BY CustNo, Date DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YTH73307)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ CustNo ║ Status ║        Date         ║
╠════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ C      ║ 24.03.2016 00:00:00 ║
║      1 ║ A      ║ 17.01.2016 00:00:00 ║
║      1 ║ C      ║ 04.12.2015 00:00:00 ║
║      2 ║ B      ║ 28.04.2016 00:00:00 ║
║      2 ║ C      ║ 25.03.2016 00:00:00 ║
║      3 ║ A      ║ 02.02.2016 00:00:00 ║
╚════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```